# How do I return results from multiple queries (that have been looped) in one table?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

In plpgsql, I'd like to use results from query A to execute several queries (queries B), and return the results of all B queries as one table, but I'm not sure how to do this. Do I use the 'RETURN QUERY' functionality in plpgsql?

Here's an example. The function finds all zip_code records with the given code, and then searches all locations for a state of that original zip_code. (I know the current query could be done via a join, but my ACTUAL query would require this functionality.)

```
begin;
create OR REPLACE function t() returns setof locations as
$$
declare z zip_codes%rowtype;
begin
  for z in select * from zip_codes where code like '%32301%'
  LOOP
    return query select * from locations where locations.state like z.state; #query B 
        # All I want to do is return the results from all of the above queries as one
        # result set.
  END LOOP;
  return;
end
$$
language 'plpgsql';
commit;
```

Any idea how I do that?

Comment: I've noticed several people have looked at the question, but no answer attempts yet...any way I can entice some tries?

Comment: I don't see a reason to use two nested selects here. If you think they are really necessary you should post your actual code and what you real problem/intention is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a temporary table, fill it with the result of each loop, and finally return the content of the temp table.

```
select * into temporary resulttbl from locations where 1 = 2
...
loop
    insert into resulttbl select ...
end loop
...
return query select * from resulttbl
```

EDIT

OR you can use your code snippet in your question. It should work (like you said in the comment, the doc says it's possible to do that). Do you have errors?

Comment: Thanks Endy!!! This is very close to what I was looking for! Here's the part of the documentation that confuses me: "RETURN QUERY appends the results of executing a query to the function's result set. RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY can be freely intermixed in a single set-returning function, in which case their results will be concatenated. " from http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html   To me, that sounds like I should be able to put a RETURN QUERY statement INSIDE a loop, and then the query will return the concatenated results. Does that make sense?

Comment: I double-checked my code and it appears that the return-query was working as expected...Thank you Endy!!!

Answer (score 0):

Consider returning the rows directly, using a single statement:

```
return query
select locations.*
from locations
join zip_codes on zip_codes.state = locations.state
where zip_codes like '%32301%';
```

Comment: Sorry homes, but this does not address the question.

Comment: Seems to me that it does... But I suppose it's your call. :-)